# Lucene - EnglishAnalyzer

Tags: lucene

I'm working with Lucene Version 4.7 and when i do something like this:

```
Analyzer analyzer 
  = new EnglishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);
```

I get a tipemismatch. any ideas about? found a lot of examples of doing this and it's supposed to work.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have `lucene-analyzers-common-4.7.0.jar` in your classpath? Also, any chances of you importing `Version` class from another package?

Comment: yes, i found it, i have a version coflit with the analyzer package, have both lucene-analyzers 3.6.2 and lucene-analyzers-common 4.7.0. Thanks!!!!